# How to calculate how many null values are present in each column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table A like this :

<kbd>**`col1`**</kbd><kbd>**`col2`**</kbd><kbd>**`col3`**</kbd>
   <kbd>`1`</kbd>   <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`null`</kbd>
<kbd>`null`</kbd><kbd>`null`</kbd><kbd>`null`</kbd>
   <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`null`</kbd><kbd>`null`</kbd>
<kbd>`null`</kbd>   <kbd>`5`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>

I want an output like this in **Oracle 10G** :

<kbd>**`column_name`**</kbd><kbd>**`null_count`**</kbd>
<kbd>`col1`</kbd>                <kbd>`2`</kbd>
<kbd>`col2`</kbd>                <kbd>`2`</kbd>
<kbd>`col3`</kbd>                <kbd>`3`</kbd>

I have achieved this using **UNION ALL** like this:

```
select "col1" column_name,sum(case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_count from A group by "col1"
union all
select "col2" column_name,sum(case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_count from A group by "col2"
union all
select "col3" column_name,sum(case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_count from A group by "col3";
```

It is working fine , but it is taking lots of time , as there are nearly 100 **UNION ALL**s . I want to achieve the same output without using **UNION ALL**.

> Is there any way to achieve this without using **UNION ALL** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNPIVOT for that (I am not sure if the ancient Oracle 10 already supported that - I haven't used that for over a decade)

```
select colname, count(*) - count(val) as num_nulls
from t1
  UNPIVOT include nulls 
      (val for colname in (col1 as 'C1', 
                           col2 as 'C2', 
                           col3 as 'C3'))
group by colname
order by colname;
```

Not sure if that is faster though.

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e807b8b2d8080abac36574f776dbf04

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: But it is causing problem when the datatypes of the columns are  different.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 10g doesn't support the UNPIVOT and PIVOT operators, so to do what you're after in 10g, you'd need to use a dummy table (containing the same number of rows as columns being unpivoted - in your case, that's 3), like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 col1, 0 col2, NULL col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL col1, NULL col2, NULL col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 col1, NULL col2, NULL col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL col1, 5 col2, 1 col3 FROM dual)
SELECT CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN 'col1'
            WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN 'col2'
            WHEN dummy.id = 3 THEN 'col3'
       END column_name,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 END
                  WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 END
                  WHEN dummy.id = 3 THEN CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 END
             END) null_count
FROM   your_table
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL ID
                   FROM   dual
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) dummy
GROUP BY dummy.id;

COLUMN_NAME NULL_COUNT
----------- ----------
col1                 2
col2                 2
col3                 3
```

If you think that will take an age to write for a large number of columns, you can always write a query that will generate the bulk of the case statements yourself, e.g.:

```
SELECT 'when dummy.id = '||row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY owner, table_name ORDER BY column_id)||' then '''||LOWER(column_name)||'''' first_part,
       'when dummy.id = '||row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY owner, table_name ORDER BY column_id)||' then case when '||column_name||' is null then 1 end' second_part
FROM   all_tab_columns a
WHERE  owner = ...
AND    table_name = ...
-- and column_name in (...)
ORDER BY column_id;
```

(I included the `row_number()` analytic function rather than using column_id because if you're excluding some columns, the column_id column will no longer be consecutive numbers starting with 1.)